# Startup Dreamweaver CS4 in codemode

Tags: boot, dreamweaver

How do you tweak Dreamweaver CS4 to always startup in codemode and not designmode?

Answer (score 1):

When you select **Code** in **Layout Mode**, this will make it the default view mode.

Comment: Yes I have checked Code but when I start fresh it starts up in Design despite this?